# Having issue with group function

Tags: mysql, sql

```
User     Product     count    Percentage 
User1    Product1     21        38.1818
User1    Product2     34        61.8182
```

The "Percentage" mentioned above has been calculated by count/total_count*100. I have the below code achieve this.

```
select user, product, count(id) as count, count(id)/55*100 from table1 where  
user=user1 group by product.
```

But the number 55 has been hard coded. I dont want that to be hard coded. Hence How can I achieve this. I tried with best of my knowledge, but did work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, you would use a `join`/correlated subquery :

```
select user, product, count(id) as count,
       count(id) / (select count(*) from table1 tt1 where tt1.user = t1.user)
from table1 t1
where t1.user = user1
group by user, product;
```

In MySQL 8.0+, you can just use a window function:

```
select user, product, count(id) as count,
       count(id) / sum(count(*)) over (partition by user)
from table1 t1
where t1.user = user1
group by user, product;
```